# right click menu from a button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, right-click

I'm trying to get a right click menu to appear by right clicking a button, while still allowing left click to do something else.

**Main.py**

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,disable_multitouch')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.bubble import Bubble

class MainWidget(FloatLayout):

    def onpressed(self, widget, touch):
        if touch.button == 'left':
            print("LEFT")
        elif touch.button == 'right':
            print("RIGHT")
            ccp = CutCopyPaste
            self.add_widget(ccp)

class CutCopyPaste(Bubble):
    pass

class RightClickApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RightClickApp().run()
```

**rightclick.kv**

```
MainWidget:

<MainWidget>:
    Button:
        text: "A"
        on_touch_down: root.onpressed

<CutCopyPaste>:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (160, 160)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .6}
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Cut'
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Copy'
    BubbleButton:
        text: 'Paste'
```

All the ways I've found to do this haven't worked. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two small problems with your code:

1. Your `onpressed()` method is missing `()`. Just change `ccp = CutCopyPaste` to `ccp = CutCopyPaste()`.
2. You are also missing `()` in your `kv` file, as well as arguments to the `onpressed()` method. Just change `on_touch_down: root.onpressed` to `on_touch_down: root.onpressed(*args)`.

See the [documentation concerning `args` in `kv`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with the () and it didn't work but what I didn't know was I had to have (*args) in the kv file.